# ASP.NET/MVC : The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a method defined in ApiController. When the method is defined like this :

```
public IEnumerable<QuestionResponse> Get()
```

Everything is fine. However I want to pass a parameter to that method but when I define that method as

```
public IEnumerable<QuestionResponse> Get(int parid)
```

The response is a 405 "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'".

When there's no parameter defined for the method then both of these urls are routed to the method :

```
/api/questionresponse/224809
/api/questionresponse
```

But when I define an argument to that method both of those urls result in a 405 .

Help ?

---

FWIW

- the request is being made from some jquery on a page served from within the same project
- I've based what I've done to date on this text http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api .
- the results I'm describing here are all when run from within Visual Studio 2015 .

Comment: Try changing your parameter name from parid to id, it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the route you can see the default template makes use of parameter `{id}`

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
                name: "DefaultApi", 
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

So you need to change the controller signature to

```
public IEnumerable<QuestionResponse> Get(int id)
```

Or write a Custom route to support parameter `parid`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate it. I can see the logic of your suggestion but when I rename the argument I still get the same result.. SORRY CANCEL THAT ... I didn't test it properly. Just testing again.

Comment: thank you very much that is indeed the answer. I had looked at the WebApiConfig.cs but I was thinking the 'id' was a placeholder rather than an actual name mapping ...not sure why I would think that ! Thanks again.